# Get a warning when forgetting to call super

Tags: ios

Is there a way to get a compiler warning when I implement a Cocoa method and forget to call super. E.g. if I forget to call `[super viewDidLoad]` within `- (void)viewDidLoad`

Update: I'd like to receive the warning for overriding a method written by others (e.g. iOS Frameworks). The question is not about writing my own method signatures but rather about warnings I'd like to receive when forgetting to call super when overriding someone else's method.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this by adding `__attribute__((objc_requires_super))` behind your method declaration in your interface file

```
- (void)myBaseClassMethod __attribute__((objc_requires_super));
```

After adding this to the method declaration, you will receive the following warning in all subclasses:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is only useful for my own methods. I was rather talking about receiving warning when forgetting to call super in overridden methods by iOS Frameworks.